# Stream catch-up in Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I have to do catch-up of a stream which is already completed for that day, so when ever it rerun it has to check with stream completed date less than current date , then the stream has to run else it has to exit.

We have tried creating pipeline with Ifcondition, Foreach, but seems there are limitations with that

Comment: Please give a better description of your scenario. Which tool are you using for the stream?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks a lot for getting back to me..currently using Azure Data Factory V2 , tried creating pipeline with the help of Until activity, so got struck for my scenario, where we have to do catch-up the stream in case if the stream run date is less than the current date, which means ..if stream run date is 28th, and current date is 31st, which is less 28<31 , so the stream had to run for 29th, 30th like that...it has to check for loop iterations and run the entire stream.